# keep two div block inline while resizing browser to its smallest width

Tags: html, css, web

In the following html layout I want the two div tags with 'section' and 'nav' id stay next to each other, for any browser width and even resizing the browser to the smallest width, keep them them inline. I tried many css codes from the web but I could not find any solution, is it possible and How could I resolve this problem. By the way I could give a fixed width to the 'nav' div but the 'section' div width should be kept auto.

```css
#header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav {
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
#section {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px 20px;
}
#footer {
  position: initial;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="nav">
    One<br>
    Two<br>
  </div>
  <div id="section">
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>
      London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
      with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Copyright © stackoverflow.com</div>
```

Comment: Make a parent Element and give it a width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS as below: You should use % width on nav and sections, making sure they don't add up beyond 100% of parent

```
#header {
           text-align:center;
           padding:5px;
       }
       #content {
           margin:0 auto;
           width:100%;
           float:left;
           display: inline-block; 
       }
       #nav {
           line-height:30px;
           float:left;
           padding:5px;
            max-width: 48%; 
       }
       #section {
           float:right;
           padding:10px;
           border-top-left-radius:20px 20px;
           max-width: 48%; 
       }
       #footer {
           position: initial;
           clear:both;
           text-align:center;
           padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks It was clever trick, but one more problem remains when I give the nav max-width of 15% and section max-width of 75% every thing is OK. but when I give the section max-width of 80% at the minimum size of the browser the two div fall to a column rather than a line and I think it's something related to the padding attribute since, the addition of two width is below 100%. any idea how this happens

Comment: That because on resize on resize your max-width is 80% and nav is 15% , totaled to 105% , which  makes section break line.

Comment: I am sure 80% and 15% totaled to 95% not 105%.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```css
#nav {
  float: left;
  max-width: 75%; /* A maximum width to prevent it from
                     becoming wider than window. */
}
#section {
  float: none; /* Default value */
}
#content, #section {
  overflow: hidden; /* Clear float */
}
```

```css
#header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav {
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 75%;
  padding: 5px;
}
#section {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px 20px;
}
#footer {
  position: initial;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="nav">
    One<br>
    Two<br>
  </div>
  <div id="section">
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>
      London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
      with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Copyright © stackoverflow.com</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give both divs a width of 50% and float them left - should work.